# Add Switchable Encrypted USB Backup Drive to Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, encryption, usb

So my boss has decided that she wants a backup USB drive for a Windows Server 2008, but it needs 2 features...

1. HIPPA grade encryption.
2. She wants it to be switchable. She wants 2 USB drives, one on her at all times and the other plugged in and she'll switch them with each other daily.

**Bonus:** she'd prefer for it to be seamless when plugged into server and if needed, password decryption on separate machine in case of catastrophic failure or fire.

I saw something about BitLocker, but not sure of this will do it.

Comment: You mentioned to use it for Windows 2003... you know that Windows 2003 is EOL? So i would inform your boss that if he wish to ride the security train you should replace that asap!

Comment: I'm not 100% on which it is. Will double check when back at the office tonight.

Comment: It's 2008, not 2003

Answer (score 0):

Use bitlocker to go on the usb drive and add a password.  That should satisfy the requirements.